# Netctl is slow in arch linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, boot, netctl

I am new to Linux. I am working on a speed up boot-time project. I am using Arch Linux on raspberry pi B+. I am particularly looking into netctl service. To trace down function time, I have edited some of scripts in /usr/lib/network. and I got to know that, it's slow hardware(?) and also stuck up in resolv.conf as it can't find /etc/resolv.conf.

```
[   17.174115] alarmpi network[195]: Starting network profile 'ethernet-static'...
[   17.190230] alarmpi network[195]: start connection up {network}
[   17.208285] alarmpi network[195]: inside ethernet up
[   17.208285] alarmpi network[195]: test for bring interface up
[   17.443234] alarmpi network[195]: inside bring interface up{network}
[   17.455252] alarmpi network[195]: connection slow or cable is not connectedP{ethernet connection}
[   19.038800] alarmpi network[195]: wait over for carrier whose connection is low or cable not connected {ethernet connection}
[   19.056395] alarmpi network[195]: set ip in IP lib
[   19.056395] alarmpi network[195]: inside ip set {ip}
[   19.112173] alarmpi network[195]: adding static IP routs {set_ip}
[   19.122707] alarmpi network[195]: adding custome gateway {set_ip}
[   19.174517] alarmpi network[195]: start resolvconf
[   21.425880] alarmpi network[195]: /usr/lib/resolvconf/libc: line 230: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
[   21.901427] alarmpi network[195]: end resolvconf
[   21.913711] alarmpi network[195]: end of IP set
[   21.913711] alarmpi network[195]: set ip function finish P{ethernet connection}
[   21.941763] alarmpi network[195]: Started network profile 'ethernet-static'
```

code snippet for slow hardware(?) is given below.

```
if is_yes "${SkipNoCarrier:-no}"; then
    SkipDAD=yes
else
    # Some cards are plain slow to come up. Don't fail immediately.
    if ! timeout_wait "${TimeoutCarrier:-5}" '(( $(< "/sys/class/net/$Interface/carrier") ))'; then
        report_error "No connection found on interface '$Interface' (timeout)"
        bring_interface_down "$Interface"
        return 1
    fi
fi
```

this is my ethernet profile

```
Description='A basic static ethernet connection'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('10.152.187.5/24')
#Routes=('192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2')
Gateway='0.0.0.0'
DNS=('10.152.187.5')
#ForceConnect=yes
NETCTL_DEBUG=no
TimeoutCarrier=2

## For IPv6 autoconfiguration
#IP6=stateless

## For IPv6 static address configuration
#IP6=static
#Address6=('1234:5678:9abc:def::1/64' '1234:3456::123/96')
#Routes6=('abcd::1234')
#Gateway6='1234:0:123::abcd'
```

I am using static connection and I have disabled DHCP service and, as of now, I am not interested in IPv6.

What could be the solution to speed up boot time? Should I switch to systemd-networkd service?

Answer (score 0):

libc uses /etc/nsswitch.conf to configure name resolution. see man nsswitch.conf

if your hosts entry are resolved using dns at some point, this subsystem will read /etc/resolv.conf looking for parameters.

consider using only a local dns cache to speed up DNS. If a dnsmasq is considered too much you can directly use static /etc/hosts file for name resolution.

to speed up carrier link going up you should consider using spanning tree portfast on the switch link to that interface on you PI.